# Landscape app on modal presentation style iOS 13

Tags: ios, objective-c, uimodalpresentationstyle

Is any restriction on iOS 13 on orientation Landscape,  for modal presentation style View Controllers? 
For fullScreen presentation style works, but on modal freezing and crashes.

[image]
App delegate:

```
 - (UIInterfaceOrientationMask)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window {
    if (self.shouldRotate) {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
    } else {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
    }
```

Func:

```
-(void) restrictRotation:(BOOL) restriction {
    AppDelegate* appDelegate = (AppDelegate*)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
    appDelegate.shouldRotate = restriction;
}
```

viewWillAppear

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self restrictRotation:YES];
}
```